# Algorithm to Generate Alphabetic String That is Alphabetically Between Two Other Strings?

Tags: algorithm

A problem I'm trying to solve: given that you have two distinct strings composed of the lower case letters a through z, find a string between the two strings such that further in-between strings can always be found.

Further detail:

Given that 'a' comes before 'b' alphabetically, there are an infinite number of strings between 'a' and 'b', when sorted as a dictionary would: 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'ab', 'aba', etc. However, there are not an infinite number of strings between all strings - nothing comes between 'a' and 'aa'. Further, between 'a' and 'aaa' there exists only one in-between string 'aa'.

What is an algorithm that can find a string X that comes alphabetically between 'a' and 'b' that also satisfies the condition that there are infinite number of strings between 'a' and X as well as X and 'b'?

Comment: Hint: there are also an infinite number of numbers (decimals) between 1 and 2.

Comment: @zenzen: just one is needed, as long as it's guaranteed to work assuming the original inputs meet the condition that there exist an infinite number of strings between them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a new string that sorts between two given strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923376/return-a-new-string-that-sorts-between-two-given-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming that one can insert an infinite number of strings between the two strings.

If the lower string is shorter, add as many 'a's as to make the lengths equal then add a 'b' to the middle string.  If the upper word is shorter  make the middle string equal the lower string and append z to the middle string.  If the two strings have equal length, use either method.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. If the words were 'ab' and 'b', what would the in-between word be?

Comment: This algorithm as shown when I write this comment produces a string greater than B, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You have stated everything you need to know to find a solution. Basically, a finite number of strings exist only if one string is a prefix of the other and the rest is a string of "a"s.

Otherwise, you can find an infinite number of in-between strings.