# Reranking items without changing ranks of all items

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, ranking, rank

I have a list of items, each of which has a rank associated to it.

```
Item 1, Rank=1
Item 2, Rank=2
Item 3, Rank=3
Item 4, Rank=4
Item 5, Rank=5
```

I want to design a method which handles re-ranking of items with minimal or no changes to the ranks of other items.

One solution I thought of was to leverage decimals and use Java's double variable type. So for example if I move item5 between item2 and item3, this would be the output -

```
Item 1, Rank=1
Item 2, Rank=2
Item 5, Rank=2.5
Item 3, Rank=3
Item 4, Rank=4
```

And so on,

```
Item 1, Rank=1
Item 2, Rank=2
Item 4, Rank=2.25
Item 5, Rank=2.5
Item 3, Rank=3
```

This solutions works, but after some point (~55 moves at the same position, I reach the double variable limit and i will probably have to reset all ranks at that point)

I was just wondering if there is some better way to solve this problem?

A few things to keep in mind.

- I need to store this data structure in a database (Item, Rank) and I will be building a web service which gets all items in a sorted order based on rank so I would be making a DB call to get all items sorted by the rank field.
- I will be using Java so I can only deal with Java variables.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model - I know this is ruby/rails and not java, but you could look at their implementation and take a few notes. They use very large spaces between ranks to achieve their goals of being able to change things without changing the entire rank.

Comment: What data structure are you using? Linked lists allow for O(1) insertion into lists once you've iterated up to the desired index. Then you could use the structural location of the item within the list to indicate the rank.

Comment: I actually thought of that solution too. But then again I would just be extending my range and I will reach the limit at a later point. Thanks for pointing me to the github though....:)

Comment: @4castle - All these item objects are stored in the database. I would have to store the links in the DB incase the items have to act like a persisted linked list. Do you have some suggestion here on how I can optimize it?

Comment: I've never designed a linked list within a database before, but I'd imagine it would require that each record has a foreign key for the id of the next element in the list. It may be that the database you're using already has features for linked-list-type structures.

Comment: @4castle - unfortunately that is not an option for me to add more fields to support a linked list type structure and my database also doesn't support it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Well the more information you're able to share, the better suggestions you can get.

Comment: If you're completely unable to change the structure of your current database, then the only other suggestion I have is to force a rebalance of all the nearby ranks every time two ranks get within a certain distance of one another.

Comment: This is a similar question, but with string keys instead of numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923376/return-a-new-string-that-sorts-between-two-given-strings/38927158#38927158

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/70247523/885464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about writing a small routine that evenly distributes the rank values of a range of elements in the array (or list or whatever)?

If you insert a new element at position x you pass the elements of range `x-1 .. x+1` into the subroutine. the rank values at start and end position stay the same, the others are calculated with even distance. If successful, return true. Now, if the distance gets too small you return  false, the caller extends the range to `x-2 .. x+2` and goes into the subroutine again.

You'd have to take care about hitting array boundaries or even running out of value-space altogether.

Answer (score 2):

There are could be multiple solutions, here is one I'd prefer

I'd split this problem into multiple isolated ones:

1. In your java backend you want to have list of items, sorted in some way, with possibility to do quick O(1) changes in order.

The best structure - double linked list. You will need to use hashmap to find objects by item name/id quickly in this list.

You can store such structure into database easily, just add two foreign keys to items table. During storing you will have to update only affected rows (having in mind that prev/next items are also affected when you move item). It will look like multiple `update table set prev=?, next=? where id=?`

2. In your java service you want to display sorted list of items as fast as possible, probably paginated.

The best structure - pre-sorted array.

To store such structure in database you need column where position will be stored (rank). Of course you need index on this column.

To retrieve such structure you will use very simple, fast and efficient query, like `select item from table order by rank limit ?,?`.

---

Now you have contradiction, your data structure for edit does not match your data structure for retrieval and any attempt to use single data structure for both problems will result in performance degrade in one part, lets solve this problem independently:

3. You will create separate asynchronous service (cron job), which will read data from one table, convert (re-calculate rank for all items) and store in another table.

Here you will have two options: either completely replace data in 2nd table after calculate or find diff and update only changed rows. I believe complete replace is easier to implement and actually it could be much faster.

So, with this approach customer visible parts of your system performs great (data management part and data displaying part works as fast as it is possible).

The only problem is change propagation, which is usually fine and most users will accepts it as reasonable trade off.