# Regex list all results that are alphabetically between two strings

Tags: regex

I would like to make a Regular Expression which takes two strings and finds all the results that are alphabetically between the two.

For example:

- String 1: "**Mu**"
- String 2: "**Pi**"

The regular expression should return all the values which start anywhere between Pi and Mu and have any number of characters.

*Music* would qualify, as well as *Peace* or *Pace*.

I can see that the below thread is conveying the idea of what I am trying to do:

[Algorithm to Generate Alphabetic String That is Alphabetically Between Two Other Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367787/algorithm-to-generate-alphabetic-string-that-is-alphabetically-between-two-other)

Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think using a regex is appropriate to check if a word is between Mu and Pi. What language do you use?

Comment: Per the program I am using, regex is the only tool that I can use to perform the search that I am trying to accomplish

Comment: First clarify what "all results" means.  Is that all words that match no matter where they occur?  Next, regex patterns do not take parameters... so the two strings would need to be coded into the pattern.  If you need a parameterized search, you'll need to generate the pattern using other code.

Comment: I'm lost a bit - If you're looking between `Mu` and `Pi` wouldn't the examples you gave **not** qualify?

Comment: @JohnBustos I agree. Only Pineapple should qualify whereas Mist or Pretzel should not.

Comment: C Perkins: All results means any string that alphabetically is between Pi*-Mu

Comment: @AmanChhabra  No, Pineapple does not appear between `Mu` and `Pi`.

Comment: @JohnBustos Yeah right! my bad.

Comment: @JohnBustos, forgive me if I was not clear because I am new to Regex. Mist should qualify because Mist has starting letters that are between Pi and Mu. Same with Pretzel because Pr* comes after Pi alphabetically and before Mu alphabetically

Comment: @AmanChhabra you are right, I forgot that P comes after M...

Comment: I know this isn't your question and you've said you only want to use Regex, but I think you're using the wrong tool for this job. You could use nearly ANY programming language to do this in just a couple of lines. One example of how you could do it would be: (1) Pull words into a list, (2) Add "Mu" and "Pi" to the list (3) Order Alphabetically (here's where any programming language is very well suited for that task) (4) Take all words between "Mu" and "Pi".
Again, I know it's not your question, but I'd strongly suggest always trying to see which tool is best suited for the job at hand.

Answer (score 2):

May be below regex is what you are looking for:

```
^([Mm][U-Zu-z]+[\w]*|[NnOo][\w]*|[Pp][A-Ha-h]+[\w]*)$
```

In this case, you have two make some changes at program level as well to create regex, but I think above one gives you an idea for all words between Mu and Pi

[image]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/GR10uj/2)

Comment: This matches the `neapple` in Pineapple

Comment: @pkpkpk Just add starting and ending symbol as well and it will work. Please see updated regex and screenshot

Comment: But when I asked for clarification from the OP about the scope of the match, the response I got was "any string".  There is no restriction about word boundary, etc.  So `neapple` should match.  For that matter, `nea` or `n` would also satisfy "any string".

Comment: @AmanChhabra this is what I am trying to do! I was an idiot and accidentally forgot that p comes after m so I have edited my original post Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CPerkins The motive here is to give a basic idea. However, starting and ending symbols can be added or not  depends upon the requirement and can be changed accordingly